# How to exclude Hover for Active LI (Menu)?

Tags: html, css

I have created a Navigation menu in CSS. If a item (`LI`) is `active` how to prevent that to be hover-able?

CSS below:

```
.page-header .menu li {
    float:left;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 2px;
    line-height: 34px;
} 

.page-header .menu li a.active {
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
}

.page-header .menu li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="active" href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

-

`class="active"` should disallow hover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out select it:

```
.page-header .menu li a.active,
.page-header .menu li a.active:hover {
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RSwnP/

Note, I've added the `a.active:hover`, but also note [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) is overriding it here. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RSwnP/2/) for an example (you may or may not want to use) in which I've made one "less specific" than the other; I've removed the `li` from the `:hover` selector.